# How can I view my northbridge, hypertransport, and RAM speed in Linux?

Tags: hardware, system-info

I am trying to tweak the settings in my BIOS and was hoping to be able to double check that things are running as I set them. I know how to check CPU clocks and lots of other info with `dmidecode`, `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, cat /proc/meminfo`,`sensors`,and`lscpu`.

I also use GUI tools like `hardinfo` and `I-NEX` but I can't seem to find `northbridge`, `hypertransport`, or `RAM` speed!

Answer (score 1):

#### For RAM speed

you can use the `dmidecode`:

```
sudo dmidecode --type memory | grep Speed
```

OR use `lshw`:

```
sudo lshw -short -C memory
```

A northbridge known also host bridge  and hypertransport can be found by the command `lshw`:

```
sudo lshw
```

you can redirect the output to a text file:

```
sudo lshw  > hwFile.txt
```

Then search in hwFile for host bridge and hypertransport

Here is sample of mine:

```
description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E5/Core i7 DMI2
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
```

Comment: Thank you, Mathux! It's interesting that dmidecode reports 933 MHz for my RAM while lshw reports 800 MHz. I can see host bridge but am a little confused about the clock speed. I am clocking my northbridge to 2800MHz in the BIOS. I don't see any hypertransport clock, just that my system supports it.

Comment: You are welcome. for more info please take a look on the man page `man lshw` and `man dmidecode`